# flowtype error with redux-persist: `Cannot resolve module redux-persist`

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype, redux-persist

I am trying to get my flow coverage up for all my redux related code, and I am having a weird problem with `redux-persist` that I hope someone else has seen.

I am getting this error

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ app/javascript/bundles/Kronos/ducks/store.js:4:54

Cannot resolve module redux-persist.

     1│ // @flow
     2│
     3│ import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
     4│ import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist';
     5│ import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage';
     6│ import logger from 'redux-logger';
     7│ import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
```

I have added the `redux-persist` libs to my `.flowconfig` but this doesn't seem to make a difference:

```
[libs]
./node_modules/redux-persist/lib/index.js.flow
```

Any ideas or suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

Have you maybe mixed `yarn` installations with `npm`s?
I've reinstalled native-base (the one who broke `redux-persist` in my case) and the missing packages using npm and now it's working again